# PayPal IPN - Paypal Website Standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been following Railscasts on implementing Paypal Standard payments.
On receiving IPN notifications, i realized i wasn't receiving Item specifics like 
`item_name, item_number, & quantity`. 
After some investigation, i figured i had written them wrongly in my controller as PayPal sends the variables as `item_name1`, `item_number1`, `quantity1`, `item_name2`, `item_number2`, `quantity2` and so on

I've got the Railscasts setup. The notifications come through a controller

```
  PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery except: [:create]
     def create
       PaymentNotification.create!(params: params, 
       item_number: params[:item_number], item_name: params[:item_name], quantity: params[:quantity] 
       render nothing: true
     end
```

In a case where an order has multiple items, it would be `item_name1`, `item_name2`, `item_name3` and so on. 
What's the right way to name these variables, to be able to accept the paypal IPN notifications without adding a column for every extra item?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at the `params` before calling `PaymentNotification.create!`. Do `if params.include?(:item_name1)` to check whether there is any such key, and if so, check how many items there are by looping through the params `item_name2`, `item_name3` and so on until you find a missing param.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane If you don't mind, can you write an example as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the `params` before calling `PaymentNotification.create!`. Using a loop to check what fields are within `params`, you can count how many items there are and extract all their properties to an array. After that you can use the data in that array however you need to.

This code assumes that PayPal never sends a response with a field `item_name` – that if there is one item, they still send a field `item_name1`. I don’t know if that is actually true.

```rb
ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES = ["item_name", "item_number", "quantity"]

def extract_ipn_items_params(params)
  item_params = []

  loop do
    item_num_to_test = item_params.length + 1
    item_num_suffix = item_num_to_test.to_s
    possible_param_name = ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES[0] + item_num_suffix
    if params.include?(possible_param_name)
      this_item_params = {}
      ITEM_PARAM_PREFIXES.each do |prefix|
        this_item_params[prefix] = params[prefix + item_num_suffix]
      end
      item_params.push this_item_params
    else
      return item_params
    end
  end
end
```

Given some params like

```
{"item_name1"=>"cards", "item_number1"=>"123", "quantity1"=>"1",
 "item_name2"=>"book", "item_number2"=>"55", "quantity2"=>"2",
 "other_fields"=>"whatever"}
```

The above method should return this array of hashes:

```
[{"item_name"=>"cards", "item_number"=>"123", "quantity"=>"1"},
 {"item_name"=>"book",  "item_number"=>"55",  "quantity"=>"2"}]
```

Hopefully that format allows you to easily do whatever you need to with that information. For example, you could call `.length` on it to count how many items there were, and you could iterate over each element and pass each hash to `PaymentNotification.create!` if you wanted a separate notification for each item.

Comment: I used a `before_action :extract_ipn_items_params, only: [:create]` to trigger it but i got `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/payment_notifications_controller.rb:7:in `extract_ipn_items_params'`

Comment: @Rails_learner The error means that the function is being called with zero arguments, even though it expects one argument (`params`). You get it because the function I gave you is designed to be manually called from a controller and passed the `params` hash, not called as a model’s `before_action` where there is no `params`. I don’t know enough about your app to actually write your controller action, but I assume you want to write `items_params = extract_ipn_items_params(params)`, then do some processing with the result like I suggest in my answer’s last paragraph.

Comment: This is what my controller looks like now, how do i trigger the function manually? >> [https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f508296wb378wc/sublime.png?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f508296wb378wc/sublime.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Rails_learner Like I already wrote, just write the line `items_params = extract_ipn_items_params(params)`, within the `create` method. Then change later lines to use that new variable `items_params`. I can’t tell for sure what those lines should be, because you never said exactly why you wanted to convert the `item_name1` parameters in this way. But from your screenshot, I’m guessing you want to create one `PaymentNotification` for each item. If so, add `items_params.each do |item_params| … end`, and inside put `PaymentNotification.create!(product_title: item_params[:item_name], …)`.

Comment: @Rails_learner By the way, if you want to share a code snippet using a link, it’s better to use a “pastebin” site such as [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) rather than uploading a screenshot. Sites like Gist let the reader increase the text size without the text becoming too wide for the screen, and let the reader copy and paste the text to try running it or to post an edited version.